# A norm ratio inequality

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $y,z\in(0,1)^n$ satisfy $||y||_1 = ||z||_1=1$.

Then
$$ 
\frac{||z||_3}{||z||_2} \le
K_n 
||z/y||_\infty
\frac{||y||_3}{||y||_2}
$$
where $z/y\in\mathbb R^n$ is the coordinate-wise quotient of $z$ and $y$
and $K_n>0$ is some constant depending only on $n$.
What's the best $K_n$ that makes this true? What if $2,3$ are replaced
by general $p,q$?

Comment: It's easy to see that $1 \le K_n \le \sqrt{n}$.  Do you really need the best constant, or just some improvement on this?

Comment: For such a strange question you should give some motivation and say what you know.

Comment: My motivation is to obtain a Berry-Esseen type bound for the case where the coefficients are generated by a certain kind of partition. This probably isn't making a whole lot of sense; I'll write post a link to a short writeup soon.

Comment: @Mark -- the most interesting question is whether the best $K_n$ is actually a constant (which I suspect is not the case). The next question is -- does it grow as $n$ to some powr or slower (logarithmically, say)? The $\sqrt n$ bound is unfortunately too crude for my needs.

Comment: Here is a short writeup providing some motivation:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3198145/norm-ineq.pdf